# How to add attribute to the highest degree centrality node using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am looking for a way to increase the size of the highest degree centrality node so that I can add attributes like C1 or C2 based on their category. I have tried a solution, but it is not perfect. I want to reduce to data frame transformation and the node location code.

Ask/Help needed:
1. The data frame transformation took 15 steps before I get the df that I need. Is there any way to do it on single line?

2. To locate x,y of the label, I used trial and error method for ex. -0.186 and -0.341 but the node label is still outside not inside the center node. Is there a better way to find node's x, y values?

Please see my solution:

```
data= {        '0': [1,0,0,0,0,1],
               '1': [0,1,0,0,0,0],
               '2': [0,0,1,0,1,0],
               '3': [0,0,0,1,0,0],
       'Newspaper': ['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5','G6']
      }
df_result=pd.DataFrame(data)

df_C0=df_result[['newspaper','C0']][df_result['C0'] ==1] 
df_C1=df_result[['newspaper','C1']][df_result['C1'] ==1]
df_C2=df_result[['newspaper','C2']][df_result['C2'] ==1]
df_C3=df_result[['newspaper','C3']][df_result['C3'] ==1]

#selecting
df_C0.C0= df_C0.C0.apply(lambda x: 'C0')
df_C1.C1= df_C1.C1.apply(lambda x: 'C1') 
df_C2.C2= df_C2.C2.apply(lambda x: 'C2') 
df_C3.C3= df_C3.C3.apply(lambda x: 'C3')


#changing
col=['newspaper', 'C']
df_C0.columns=col
df_C1.columns=col
df_C2.columns=col
df_C3.columns=col

frames = [df_C0, df_C1, df_C2,df_C3]
result = pd.concat(frames)


#Creating the Graph object
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(result, 'newspaper', 'C')
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k=.25)
x0,y0=pos.get('C0')
x1,y1=pos.get('C1')
x2,y2=pos.get('C2')
x3,y3=pos.get('C3')

x0 +=-0.186
y0 +=-0.341

x1 +=-0.186
y1 +=-0.341

x2 +=-0.186
y2 +=-0.341

x3 +=-0.186
y3 +=-0.341

ax.text(x0,y0, 'C0',color='green', fontsize=15)
ax.text(x1,y1, 'C1',color='green', fontsize=15)
ax.text(x2,y2, 'C2',color='green', fontsize=15)
ax.text(x3,y3, 'C3',color='green', fontsize=15)

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, node_size=100, with_labels=False, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean it is not perfect? is the answer wrong? What's your expected output? A pandas df? or a networkx graph object?

Comment: @Tai by not perfect, I mean its code is very cumbersome, but to an extent it gets the job done. For example, the data frame transformation took 15 steps before I get the df that I need. Similarly to locate(x,y) the label, I have used adjustment numbers ( -0.186/-0.341), but it is still outside not inside the node.